# How to solve "ModuleNotFound" error in python 3.10.2?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput import keyboard
    
    COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
    ]
    current = set()
    
    def execute():
      print ("Do Something")
    
    def on_press(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                execute()
    
    def on_release(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.remove(key)
    
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    
    window= Tk()
    window.title("Platformer")
    window.configure(width=1200, height=800)
    window.configure(bg='lightgray')
    window.mainloop()
    
    mainloop()
```

Some of the code regarding pynput is from website: [How to make hotkeys in python](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-make-hotkeys-in-python/)

My problem is that despite: 1. Uninstalling and reinstalling pynput. 2. Using a different interpreter and python version. 3. Updating pip and finally re-typing everything nothing works. I keep getting *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'*

Help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S I understand many of you are veterans, but this issue has been bothering me for a week and I can't find help.

-A newbie python user

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct `pip`?
You can check the `pip` you are using with this command:

```
pip --version
```

If it's showing another python version, it means you're not using the correct pip. For example, this is the output when I run this command:

```
pip 22.0.3 from /home/mohammad/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Now, if I'm using another python that is not in the path it mentioned (or another python version), I'm using another python's pip.

One solution could be installing your modules this way:

```
python -m pip install your_packages_here
```

Comment: I am certain I am using the correct pip version/the most modern. As for the solution, I get "No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'". Btw thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @Powerlevel9000spy After running `python -m pip install pynput`, you're getting the error you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error.